# That secondary adjectival form for two-nation matters

Tags: adjectives, international

In English, we know each country or nation has its own derived adjective. Examples

- England - English
- Wales - Welsh
- Poland - Polish
- France - French
- China - Chinese
- India - Indian
- Russia - Russian
- etc

However when referring to two nations in a common subject matter, the first nation's adjective can get transformed into a secondary form that I am not sure of their origin and true purpose. (Was not taught anything about this as a school kid)

- Anglo-French wars
- Franco-German competition
- Sino-Japanese war
- Russo-Turkish war
- Anglo-American forces
- Indo-Pakistani tensions
- etc

My main probe is what exactly is the benefit of using that form? Is there some disadvantage to just plainly say for example "English-French wars"?

And then the follow-up question as to the origin of these forms - when were they first (individually) introduced into English language? Surely something must have happened that triggered the existence and usage of (and necessitated?) these secondary forms, but I don't know why and when.

Furthermore, as far as I've seen, not every nation on the planet has the "honour" of owning this secondary form, so what rules for consistency when pairing up two nations together for a subject matter is beyond me.

Comment: The *full* (subscription-only) OED says that ***French*** was *Formed within English, **by derivation***. But they say the "combining form" ***Franco-*** was *A borrowing from Latin*, and that ***Germano-*** was *A borrowing from Latin, **combined with English elements**.*

Comment: My guess would be Latinate forms sound more poetic.

Comment: So these have their roots from Latin? Which sounds optional to me then.

Answer (score 2):

So far as ***Anglo*** is concerned, it originates from post-classical Latin, the earliest examples being **from the late-sixteenth century**. Perhaps the earliest such combination was ***Anglo-Saxon***, meaning an English person of Saxon origin.

The OED has a substantial reference on ***Anglo-Saxon*** with a lot on the etymology. It follows the classical Latin and Greek form of adjectival connection, such as *sacrosanctus* - "sacredly sanctified".

All of these forms, such as Franco, Germano, Indo etc are undoubtedly borrowings from Latin.

Of course the term ***Anglo-American*** has more than one meaning. One can speak, for example of an *Anglo-American corporation*, or let's say *Anglo-American ideas* etc meaning a combination of the two. There is however another way in which *Anglo-American* is used - meaning an American of English origin. This is a much later sense, and appears in the nineteenth century.

*Anglo-Indian* can mean either a person of mixed English and Indian ethnicity, or it could mean an Indian of English origin i.e. typically during the Raj, a white person settled in India.

> Etymology: < post-classical Latin Anglo-Saxones the English people,
>   sometimes (in British sources) apparently spec. the West Saxons
>   together with the Mercians (860, a1010 in continental sources; from
>   10th cent. in British sources) < Anglo- , combining form of classical
>   Latin Anglus (see Angle n.3) + post-classical Latin Saxones , plural
>   of Saxon- , Saxo Saxon n.; compare the earlier collocation Angli
>   Saxones , Saxones Angli , lit. ‘the English Saxons’, the English
>   people, in contradistinction to the continental Saxons (8th cent. in a
>   continental source). With use with reference to Old English compare
>   earlier Saxon n. 2. In post-classical Latin Anglo-Saxones , Anglo- ,
>   combining form, is used adverbially, as in similar Latin and Greek
>   compounds, e.g. classical Latin sacrōsanctus sacredly sanctioned (see
>   sacrosanct adj.), Hellenistic Greek Ἰνδοσκυθία Indian Scythia, Scythia
>   of the Indus (compare Indo-Scythian adj. at Indo- comb. form1 2),
>   Hellenistic Greek Συροϕοῖνιξ , classical Latin Syrophoenix ,
>   Phoenician of Syria (see Syrophœnician n.). Compare also classical
>   Latin Gallograecī (see Gallo-greeks n. at Gallo- comb. form1 1b).
>
> > Post-classical Latin Anglo-Saxones , which had become rare after the
> >     Norman Conquest, was apparently revived in historical use by Camden
> >     (writing in Latin) in the late 16th cent.: 1586   W. Camden Brit. 43
> >     (running title)    Anglo-Saxones. 1607   W. Camden Brit. (rev. ed.) 94
> >     Nunc..Anglo-Saxones ad differentiam eorum in Germania, vocatos. 1607
> >     W. Camden Brit. (rev. ed.) 128   Maiores nostri Anglo-Saxones
> >     Wittena-ge-mott, .i. Prudentum Conuentus..vocârunt. Compare earlier
> >     English-Saxon adj.    Compare also earlier use of Angle-Saxon denoting
> >     Old English ( < Angle n.3 + Saxon n., after post-classical Latin
> >     Anglo-Saxones): 1589   G. Puttenham Arte Eng. Poesie (new ed.) iii.
> >     iv. 120   I meane the speach..so is ours at this day the Norman
> >     English. Before the Conquest of the Normans it was the Anglesaxon, and
> >     before that the British.

Comment: So these have their roots from Latin? Which sounds optional to me then.